# Check if Cell A is greater than values in Cell B and C

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am in need of some help, I have created a spreadsheet with several columns, but not sure how to implement an if statement to check if content in Column A is greater than Column B and Column C. These are the columns:

- Column A: % of pupils meeting Expected standards
- Column B: LEA Score Column
- Column C: Across England Score

This is what I tried so far:

```
=IF((A1>=B1) && (A1>=C1),"yes","no")
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
=IF(AND((A1>=B1), (A1>=C1)),"Yes","No")
```

See [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9) for details on `AND` function.

Answer (score 0):

Excel doesn't like the use of &&; try the. "And(condition, condition)" function instead.
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9